# Inference in function types

Tags: typescript

In the official typescript documentation there is a trick with function arguments type inference:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#inference

Is it possible to do the same thing when we just defining the type/interface of the function?

***Original Example*** *How it works (from the official documentation):*

```js
function firstElement<T>(arr: T[]): T {
  return arr[0];
}
```

*In case if I want to define the type of the firstElement function separately, I would need to use generics:*

```js
type FirstElementFn<T> = (arr: T[]) => T;
```

*And after this, to make it work like in the original example, I need to pass generic type when declaring the function:*

```js
const firstElement: FirstElementFn<number> = (arr) => arr[0]
```

The question is: **Is it possible to define type of the function before the function itself and infer the argument types from the declaration, like in the original example?**

**UPDATE:**

This one actually works just like the original one:

```js
type FirstElementFn = <T>(arg: T[]) => T;
const firstElement: FirstElementFn = (arg) => arg[0];
```

But is it possible to enforce certain types? Like this:

```js
// This does not work
const firstStringElement: FirstElementFn = (arg: string[]) => arg[0];
```

Comment: Instead of updating the question to include the answer, it's perfectly fine, encouraged even, to post the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

This one actually works just like the original one:

```js
type FirstElementFn = <T>(arg: T[]) => T;
const firstElement: FirstElementFn = (arg) => arg[0];
```